# Help determining how external database is being used

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I've inherited a SharePoint 2010 workflow where I'm unsure exactly what it's doing.

Here is the specific line. I noticed that it's using a GUID rather than an the actual list name. I normally think something is wrong when I see a GUID referenced like this.

[image: Update item in]

Clicking on the GUID link shows me this:

[image: Update List Item]

Again here, I'm unsure why it's not defaulting the List dropdown to the list title. It shows the list name as empty. However it does show two fields. I've been able to determine these fields are located in an external database table.

I used a Powershell script to get the list name based on the GUID. The name (ECO Records) also matches up with the external database table name.

In Designer I cannot find any reference to a list or external data source named ECO Records. Am I wrong in thinking that an external data source would need to be setup in SharePoint first before it can be used in a workflow? Is it normal that the list title is showing the GUID rather than the name? Should this workflow be failing as it looks now? It's not showing an errors.

Comment: You sure the list is not using an external content type configured for BCS?  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/external-content-types-in-sharepoint

Comment: That's a good suggestion. When I click on the External Content Types in Designer for this site, I don't see any listed.